# extract results from a loop in a function

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm probably doing something very silly but I can't extract the parameter values from a series of models my function is looping through.

Data:

```
library(difR)
data(verbal)
TotScore=rowSums(verbal[,c(1:24)])
mydata=verbal[,c(1:24)]
```

I can then get the model BIC in a loop

```
library(BMA)
a<-rep(NA,length(1:24))
for (i in (1:24)){
  a[i]<-bic.glm(mydata[,i]~ TotScore, glm.family=binomial,data=mydata)$bic
}
a
```

But if I try to put this in a function I can't extract "a"

```
myB<-function(mydata){
  a<-rep(NA,length(ncol(mydata)))
  for (i in (1:ncol(mydata))){
    a[i]<-bic.glm(mydata[,i]~ TotScore, glm.family=binomial,data=mydata)$bic
  }
  return(a)
}

myB(mydata)
```

Or rather the bic is only for the very last model

I can build the same function for the mean and manage to extract the results so maybe it's something to do with the structure of the bic output?

Many thanks

M

Comment: Beyond Edward's solution, are you *sure* you're doing this correctly? I've never used the `BMA` package, but looking at the help file, it says you should be able to do something like `bic.glm(x=mydata, y=TotScore, glm.family="binomial")$bic` to get all the results at once, but that expects `y values must be 0 <= y <= 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though `bic.glm` only reads objects from the global environment - the problem with your function was that it did recognize the `i` created locally within the function. Try the following:

```
library(difR)
data(verbal)
TotScore=rowSums(verbal[,c(1:24)])
mydata=verbal[,c(1:24)]

myB<-function(mydata){
    a<-rep(NA,length(ncol(mydata)))
    for (i in (1:ncol(mydata))){
        # force this.col to be in the global environment
        this.col <<- mydata[,i]
        # Alternatively:
        # assign("this.col", mydata[,i], envir=.GlobalEnv)
        a[i]<-bic.glm(this.col ~ TotScore, glm.family=binomial,data=mydata)$bic
    }
    return(a)
}

myB(mydata)
```

Your function was still reading the global `i` created by the first loop, which was at 24.

It seems very strange that it should do this; after a quick google search I found references to the problem [here](http://projects.trophia.com/issues/182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329984/r-does-not-recall-object-in-memory) (it wasn't a very thorough search and I'm sure there are better examples). I couldn't find anything in the documentation for `bic.glm`, which is a bit surprising.

From the first answer to the second link I provided, it seems like this would happen if you use a formula but do not specify a `data` parameter.

Comment: By the way, how did you find out that it was picking up the global?It would be good to have a debugging strategy for the next time this sort of thing happens.

Comment: Since it was only picking up the last `i`, I suspected it may have been left over from the call you did before defining the function (the for loop that worked correctly). So I used `rm(list=ls())` to clear out everything and then defined and ran the function - and it threw an error complaining that it could not find `i`. It refused to find anything defined in the function, so global was my next best guess. I would hope this doesn't come up again though, or at least that it is documented when it would.