# R finding my object the first time but not the second in a ddply loop with zoo lag function -- can't figure out how to amend code

Tags: r, error-handling, plyr, zoo

I'm having a problem with a `zoo` function I've written and applying it to a dataset using `ddply` . I have tried all other of the *apply functions, and had to rename my string variable elements, but I'm still getting an error. I think I have figured out what the error is with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537273/how-does-r-handle-object-in-function-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I can't fathom a way to rectify the code. I'll put a subsect of the dataset and my code below before explaining it.

```
Name <- c("Aberavon", "Aberavon", "Aberavon", "AberdeenNorth", 
"AberdeenNorth", "AberdeenNorth")
year <- c(1964, 1966, 1970, 1964, 1966, 1970)
winner <- c("LAB", "LAB", "LIB", "CON", "CON", "CON")
dat <- data.frame(Name, year, winner)


tag_party_change <- function(x){
  x = x[order(x$year),]
  plab = zoo(x$top1_label) #this top1_label is a previous function to find 
#winner and return the labels (CON, LAB, LIB etc.)
  plab_lag = stats::lag(plab, -1, na.pad = T)
  x$pdelta = ifelse(plab == plab_lag, 0, 1)
  return(x)
}

dat_final = ddply(dat, as.quoted(dat$Name), tag_party_change)
```

So what I'm trying to do here is get R to look at the `Name` element, its previous `year`, see if there is a change in `winner` and if there is a change return `1` in a new vector, no change then `0`. So the new vector values should be `NA, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0` in the example. But I'm getting this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Aberavon' not found
```

Now from what I can figure out from previous posts (which I have used *a lot* in just getting this far!), this means that R has found `Aberavon` the first time, then goes back to look for it and it's not there -- perhaps because it stored it in the local environment the first time, then for the second time it's gone. Perhaps I need to work the `Name` variable into the function somewhere, so that there isn't this storage problem, as it will look in the dataset/global environment for its permanent place? Or maybe I'm way off the mark and it's another problem?

This code has been quite buggy, and I've had to fix issues with other *apply functions trying to get this to work, but this is the simplest error I've had returned. Really hoping someone knowledgeable can help so I can get on with this work! Thank you.

P.S. I'm fairly new to R after working with SPSS for a long time, so I hope the sample code works okay.

Comment: There might be a bunch of solutions; looking at the syntax in ```ddply``` help, you can get past this error by using ```ddply(dat, .(Name), tag_party_change)``` instead, but that gives another error because there's no ```top1_label``` in ```dat```. Using ```dplyr``` and ```purrr``` instead of ```plyr``` might be a bit easier, idk. Give us an update on how it's going.

Comment: It worked! I just had to swap out `top1_label` from the function, to `winner` (which is in the df and basically does/says/is the same thing). Thank you so much for identifying the problem, you're a star!